# Timer error after couple minutes running C#

Tags: c#, loops, time, crash, fault

I'm pretty new in c# and I'm programing just for my personal studies, I have been trying to program an instruction where a read some data from a remote station to my application (m64...mw74), it's running OK for couple minutes but its crash maybe after 5 minutes.
please see the code I'm using below to update my data every 1 second and write it in a simple text box in my form.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSSVc.png)

Thank you very much in advance.

```
private void Load_act()
    {
      actvalueL1.Text = plc.Read("mw64").ToString();
      actvaluep1.Text = plc.Read("mw68").ToString();
      actvaluep2.Text = plc.Read("mw71").ToString();
      actvaluep3.Text = plc.Read("mw74").ToString();

      InitTimer();
    }

    private Timer timer1;
    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load_act();
    }
```

Comment: what timer class are you using (i.e., what namespace/dll)?  Also, you are adding callbacks to timer1.Tick in the callback itself, so that list will grow exponentially with each tick event.

Answer (score 0):

You're chaining the timers, eventually going to run yourself out of memory as they cannot dispose - the timer creates the next with its own call. Return them on to a parent method that loops your timer 'initTimer'